# How to enable ssh on SunOs 5.10?

Tags: shell, root, ssh

I need to launch ssh daemon on a SunOs 5.10 anyone knows how to help (command, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

svcadm enable ssh

If it does not work, please open second console and type

```
tail -f /var/svc/log/network-ssh\:default.log
```

Then try again and see if anything happens. If there are any problems with the service, they should get listed in the log file.

Comment: Thankyou, the command is right, now I have to figure out why it won't start or allow me to connect. :/

Comment: You can try to check if there are any problems using 
svcs ssh

The proper output should look similar to this:
online         Jul_21   svc:/network/ssh:default

If it's online and it is still not working, please check the configuration (/etc/ssh/ssh_config).

Comment: svcs ssh gives offline state even if I started the service moments before, checked configuration file and found nothing useful, everything seems fine: listen port and addresses, protocol, X11 and else.

Comment: 'ssh -x ssh' will show you were the logfile for the service is, for me the default is /var/svc/log/network-ssh:default.log. It may contain which bit of ssh is failing. You should also check the syslog where ssh-specific errors would show up. You could also try starting sshd yourself as root with the same command line arguments as the service to see what happens.